# props dont get passed when submitting Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, ecmascript-6, react-google-maps

I'm trying to pass the Value of my Input Form to my AppMap Component, it centers the Map on the `prop city`. It works when I hardcode the state of `searchValue`, but when i submit the form it does not pass the state as a prop to the AppMap Component. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
class Map extends Component{
  constructor(){
      super()
      this.state = {
        value: ' ',
        searchValue: "London"
      };

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }



handleChange(event) {
       this.setState({value: event.target.value});
     }

handleSubmit(event) {
    const value = this.state.value
       event.preventDefault();
       this.setState ({
         searchValue: value
       })
 }


    render(){
        return(
            <div className='map'>
                <h1>The Map</h1>

                    <AppMap city={this.state.searchValue} />

                    <Grid>
                    <Row className="show-grid">
                        <FormGroup  value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} name='cardHeading' controlId="formControlsTextarea">
                          <Col xs={8} md={8}>
                            <FormControl type="text" placeholder="title" />
                          </Col>
                          <Col xs={4} md={4}>
                            <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit} type="submit">Submit</Button>
                          </Col>
                        </FormGroup>
                    </Row>
                  </Grid>
            </div>
          )
        }
    }
```

export default Map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you already check if the `state` of `Map` and the `props` of `AppMap` update correctly? For example with react dev-tools. If so then the `AppMap` Component just might be the problem.

First of all I would wrap the `FormGroup` Component with a `<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}></form>` tag and remove the `onClick={this.handleSubmit}` from the `Button` Component. (Check React Form example at https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

Then, if the `state` and `props` update correctly, but the centering of the `AppMap` Component does not work, you might have to center the map yourself using one of the `AppMap` [update lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating).

Comment: thank you i installed the react dev-tools and then i was able to see, that the component updates it's state, but nothing changed, because i wrote the fetch function of my AppMap Component in the wrong lifecycle method

Comment: If this helped, can you please set this as a useful answer?

Answer (score 0):

the handleChange function should be in the FormControl not in the FormGroup

```
<FormControl type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} name='cardHeading' placeholder="title" />
```